# How can I find the source of this unreadable hd0 in grub2?

Tags: centos, grub, uefi

On boot of a new ThinkServer with CentOS 7 installed after selecting one of the boot menu options in grub (or at the grub command shell if I `search` or `ls`), I can see `` error: failure reading sector 0x0 from `hd0' ``.

The system will boot, but the error message bothers me, I want to make it go away. I've done everything I can find in `efibootmgr` and in UEFI setup:

- SafeBoot is off
- Legacy support is off
- Can't see anything in the boot sequence in either `efibootmgr` or the UEFI setup that suggests that anything other than the hard drives is a potential boot source

But yet, the error. And if I go to the grub shell and type ls, I can see an `(hd0)` that I don't expect in addition to the `(hd1)` and `(hd2)` (and their partitions) that I do expect. I can't find anything that explains the `hd0`, and I can't find any way to get grub to tell me where `hd0` is coming from.

How can I make this error go away? How can I find where `hd0` is coming from and disable it?

Comment: That would show up as a separate device rather than a partition? If that is the source, shouldn't grub be able to read it? And is there any way to make the error message go 'way?

Comment: @fpmurphy1 a partition would be shown as hd0,0. Geoffrey: check `/boot/grub/devices.map`, that should show what linux device corresponds to `hd0`.

Comment: @wurtel.  `devices.map` does not exist by default with GRUB2. See https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Device-map.html

Comment: @GeoffreyWiseman.  Please add output of `lsblk` to your question. Also which particular disk are your booting from?

Comment: @fpmurphy1 but it might, and then it would be relevant.

Comment: I have a screenshot of `blkid` but not `lsblk`. There was no devices map. If I get the machine back to this state, I'll get `lsblk` -- right now I'm trying a reinstall with Ubuntu just to see if I get the same result (same boot manager, but ... we'll see), so I can't check it yet. ;)

Comment: For better or for worse, a reinstall with Ubuntu didn't reveal the same problem. Better in terms of getting a good outcome for me, worse in that I don't get a chance to keep diagnosing this. Thanks for the attempts to help.